# Eclipse oxygen 4.7 error while adding JDK 11 - Target directory is not JDK root

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

I am getting error while trying to add JDK 11 to eclipse oxygen 4.7.0 M2.

[image]

I also checked on Eclipse Market Place but there is not plug in available for JDK11 support.

Any suggestion to fix this error ?

Comment: You may need to update to 4.7.3, or Photon.

Comment: Oxygen is too old and as mentioned in the answer using Milestone releases is also bad practice. Use Eclipse 2018-09 with the Java 11 patch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-11-support-eclipse-2018-09-49

Basically, start by updating to 2018-09 and then that Marketplace entry. JDK 9 support was only added *after* Oxygen released with Oxygen.1a. A milestone during development won't support Java 9 or any newer release.

In general, please do not keep using a milestone for a release once that release has actually, well, been *released*.

Comment: Thanks. Issue is fixed now. I performed following steps : (1).Installed all updates. So current version of eclipse is 4.7.3a.   (2)  Went to "Help -> Install new software". Added new Eclipse update url : http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.9-P-builds (3) Installed again all supporting software related to JDK 11. And it fixed my problem.

Comment: @GunjanShah _"Installed again"_? huh? what did you install in your 3rd step?